# how to execute update operation in couchdb in java programme

Tags: java, json, couchdb

In my application I am using couchdb for storage. I want to execute update operation in which the _rev value must be change. so kindly help me what i have to do in my java program.

Comment: could you please explain more about your problem, its a little unclear what you are asking

Comment: I want to update my document of couchdb using java programming but In com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database class there is no any function for update the document so what which API I have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for reading, modifying and then saving a document is:

```
Document doc = db.getDocument("documentid1234");
doc.put("foo","bar");
db.saveDocument(doc);
```

The `doc` object will contain the `_rev` from when the document was read with the `getDocument()` call.

You don't generate the _rev value, couch does.

Comment: I want to save whole document again after modifying n no of values I am getting the modifying doc object from my object ,when i am saving this by using db.saveDocument(doc); method It is showing me Exception. Please kindly help?

Comment: What is the exception?