# How to update couchbase document from java layer?

Tags: java, json, couchbase

How to update couch base document from java layer.I need the java code to update the json documents in the couchbase.

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402979/how-to-execute-update-operation-in-couchdb-in-java-programme)

Comment: from "java layer"? there is no such thing. there is a business layer, a ui layer, ... If you "need the java code", I suggest you write it. Don't expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: @Riyash.D if it solves your purpose, i will post as an answer.

Comment: couchbase and couchDB are not the same thing

Comment: so research! much effort! very engineering!

Comment: @Stultuske .Who told you that there is no such thing in the java layer.If dont know the answer you just dont want to reply.Stop this kind of bullshit.

Comment: @ankur-singhal.Ya it solved my problem.

Comment: @Riyash.D: there is no such thing AS a Java layer.

Answer (score 3):

In Couchbase, you should be using the [`Java SDK` (link to documentation root)](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/java-intro.html).

Here is a [self contained example](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/couchbase/devguide/Updating.java) that shows storing/updating scenarios. (also look at the [example to initiate connection](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/couchbase/devguide/ConnectionBase.java) to the couchbase cluster, and the rest of the docs linked above, of course).

In your case, easiest way is to get, do the mutation and update:

```
JsonDocument doc = bucket.get(key);
doc.content().put("attribute", "newValue");
doc = bucket.update(doc);
```

There are of course additional things like error handling that you need to do (eg. Couchbase uses optimistic locking, so in this example it could report a `CASMismatchException` indicating that the document was already mutated elsewhere between the time you did a `get` and the `update`).

Comment: thank you man for the answer